Minimizing patch size with Addressables
I'm working on a cross-platform Unity game for release on mobile and on a console. Our game content is all loaded through Addressables. We want to leverage Addressables to minimize the size of patches after launch.
The Addressables documentation includes a section on Content update builds, but this section focuses on updating remote content builds which are downloaded separately from the main application. We're currently planning to build the Addressables groups for "local" use (shipping with the application) rather than "remote" (downloaded from a CDN after launching the application).
Let's think about releasing an update for iOS. We want to minimize update size for better user experience. We can't manually specify which files have changed and should be updated; we upload a full build of our application to Apple, which then generates optimized update packages which only include the files which have changed. The problem, of course, is if Unity has made unnecessary changes to large files (such as an asset bundle).

What workflow should we use to minimize update size on iOS for an application where all of the Addressables content is built as local content?

The "Content update builds overview" makes it sound as if any change to the application's code would require fully rebuilding all Addressables content; is this accurate? Does this mean that end users effectively have to re-download the entire game every time we make a code change?


